# Dilemma in a problem on GP

Tags: geometric-progressions

***PROBLEM***

If a, b, c, d are four distinct positive quantities in G.P., then show that
a + d > b + c

**Solution in the book:**

A.M. > G.M. for the first three terms

$(a+c)>2b$;       since $ac=b^2$     ................(A)

Similarly, for the last three terms

$(b+d)>2c$;       since $bd=c^2$     ................(B)

Adding (A) and (B), we get
(a + c) + (b + d) > 2b + 2c

a + d > b + c

**Solution done by me:**

where a is 1st term and r is common ratio

a=a

b=ar

c=ar^2

d=ar^3

A.M. > G.M. for the first and fourth terms

$(a+d)/2$ > root of ad

$(a+d)/2$ > 2ar root of r;            ................(A)

Similarly, for the second and third terms

$(b+c)/2$ > root of bc

$(b+c)/2$ > 2ar root of r;    ................(B)

(A) = (B), we get

a + d = b + c

***Where have i went wrong??***

Comment: Your mistake lies in the conclusion that $A = B$. It is tantamount to saying that if $x > k$ and $y > k$ then $x = y$, which is obviously not true.

Comment: but am>=gm then it is valid

Comment: $A$ holds because $AM \geq GM$. $B$ holds because $AM \geq GM$. But that does not mean that LHS of $A$ and LHS of $B$ are equal.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest that you use Mathjax. The text will be much more readable.

Comment: Note that in the book solution AM>GM, because the equality holds if $a=c$ in $a+c\ge 2\sqrt{ac}$, which is excluded by the condition "distinct quantities".

Answer (score 1):

Using AM-GM seems quite convoluted here.

Let $a=a, b = ar, c = ar^2, d = ar^3$.

$a,b,c,d$ are distinct positive $\implies$ $r$ is positive and not equal to 1.

Given inequality then boils down to proving $1 + r^3 > r(1+r)$, which is equivalent to proving $1 - r + r^2 > r \iff (1-r)^2 > 0$ which is obviously true. Strict inequality holds because $r \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG the four terms are $$A/D^3, A/D, AD, AD^3$$ where $D>0,\ne1$

$$a+d=A\left(D^3+\dfrac1{D^3}\right)$$

$$b+c=A\left(D+\dfrac1D\right)$$

$$a+d-(b+c)=A\left(D+\dfrac1D\right)\left(D^2-2+\dfrac1{D^2}\right)==A\left(D+\dfrac1D\right)\left(D-\dfrac1D\right)^2$$